# JDBCTemplate in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I need to do some reports that aren't strictly a listing-of-entities. More free-form query, hard-coded SQL, returned as arbitrary JSON.

I'm trying to use JdbcTemplate for that, and using code I've found online (eg [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringJDBC/article.html)) to construct that.

This is all inside a class called ReportViewController.

My code (with logging/debugging cruft that will be relevant later):

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private DataSource dataSource;
private UUID uuid;


public ReportViewController() {
    this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
}


public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    System.out.println("Setting data source");
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    if (this.dataSource == null) {
        System.out.println("failed to set my dataSource properly");
    }
    System.out.println("uuid: " + this.uuid);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/report/{reportId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String runNewUntypedSearch(@PathVariable Integer reportId, WebRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    //View v = View.findView(reportId); 

    System.out.println("uuid: " + this.uuid);
    if (this.dataSource == null) {
        System.out.println("lost my dataSource somewhere along the way");
    }

    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);

    List<Map<String, Object>> l = null;
    try {
        l = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select 1 as one");

        JSONSerializer s = new JSONSerializer();
        return s.serialize(l);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("querying failed -- " + e.toString());
        return "";
    }
}
```

My problem has been, despite the console indicating it's calling setDataSource(), when I get to runNewUntypedSearch(), those properties are null.

So, suspecting foul play in terms of the objects I'm talking to, I have this controller creating a UUID in its constructor, and put that out as part of its logging, as you see above.

The console output shows, in part:

```
Setting data source
hash: bc679ef1-fbdc-4ef9-9457-dd79889f973e
...
hash: bbe2b03a-92ff-4517-add8-8d9ff6480cc8
lost my dataSource somewhere along the way
```

...and then Spring responds to the browser with an "internal error" and a stack trace that indicates a null pointer where I'm trying to instantiate my jdbcTemplate.

This leads me to the conclusion that whatever object is being told to set its dataSource isn't the same instance as is being hooked in as a URL-mapped method. The "real" instance that the server runs hasn't had `getDataSource()` called on it.

Can that be? Why isn't this working?

EDIT:

web.xml (edited to remove my client's name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


    <display-name>myProjectName</display-name>

    <description>Roo generated application</description>


    <!-- Enable escaping of form submission contents -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Handles Spring requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myProjectName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myProjectName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>90</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/uncaughtException</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml (edited to remove the client's name and the Roo-generated commentary)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>


    <context:spring-configured/>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myProjectName">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>


    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" id="mailSender">
        <property name="host" value="${email.host}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage" id="templateMessage">
        <property name="from" value="${email.from}"/>
        <property name="subject" value="${email.subject}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

webmvc-config.xml (edited to remove my client's name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myProjectName" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>


    <!-- Turns on support for mapping requests to Spring MVC @Controller methods
         Also registers default Formatters and Validators for use across all @Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService"/>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources -->
    <mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static resource requests to the container's default Servlet -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <!-- register "global" interceptor beans to apply to all registered HandlerMappings -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- selects a static view for rendering without the need for an explicit controller -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/login"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/admin" view-name="admin"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/uncaughtException"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/resourceNotFound"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/dataAccessFailure"/>

    <!-- Resolves localized messages*.properties and application.properties files in the application to allow for internationalization. 
        The messages*.properties files translate Roo generated messages which are part of the admin interface, the application.properties
        resource bundle localizes all application specific messages such as entity names and menu items. -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>

    <!-- store preferred language configuration in a cookie -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale"/> 

    <!-- resolves localized <theme_name>.properties files in the classpath to allow for theme support -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource" id="themeSource"/>

    <!-- store preferred theme configuration in a cookie -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver" id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard"/>

    <!-- This bean resolves specific types of exceptions to corresponding logical - view names for error views. 
         The default behaviour of DispatcherServlet - is to propagate all exceptions to the servlet container: 
         this will happen - here with all other types of exceptions. -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
                <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
                <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
                <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- allows for integration of file upload functionality -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" id="multipartResolver"/>
  <bean class="com.mavenmanagement.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="applicationConversionService"/> 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
  </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
      <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
        <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

I see that the filtering on the annotation scan blocks `@Controller`s at the applicationContext level and enables them at the webmvc-config level. So that doesn't, I think, explain the double instantiation.

Comment: Using JdbcTemplate from your web layer is very evil. Read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: Stop naming list variables "l" !

Comment: Aside: you can inject `JdbcTemplates` directly instead of `DataSources`. I think it might be even safe to share them across threads, but if not, prototype scope will take care of that.

Comment: @Inerdial, yes, you can inject `JdbcTemplate` directly and it is thread-safe. No, you don't need `prototype` scope, which wouldn't help at all.

Comment: I tried injecting JdbcTemplate into my method, and it seemed to work, but the query failed with the exception "No DataSource specified". So I don't think that's the whole of my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hints from @Tomasz Nurkiewicz and @Inerdial in the question comments made me think a whole other way, that is way simpler and worked brilliantly, and yet I haven't seen it documented anywhere.

At the bottom of applicationContext.xml, I'm instantiating a JdbcTemplate object:

```
   <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
   </bean>
```

Then I just @AutoWire that into the controller where I need it:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

And Bob's yer uncle, I can now talk to a fully configured template object at this.jdbcTemplate.

Why this controller class was getting instantiated twice was because I was firing it up from the applicationContext.xml to try to configure its data source. Then the version instantiated by the `@Controller` annotation got created, but wasn't configured. So that was the problem there.

I also followed the other advice in the comments and moved this query function into a model-type class, and call into it from my view controller. Yes obviously DB interaction in a view controller is an abomination.

Comment: Actually it's documented in the Spring documentation as best practice: [http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-idioms]

Answer (score 2):

First of all - in Spring MVC application there are two application contexts - the main one bootstrapped via `web.xml` and `ContextLoaderListener` and the child context created by each `DispatcherServlet` (typically one).

Your controller bean is created in both contexts, you are setting the data source in the controller created in main context but Spring MVC uses the one created in child context.

Obviously, you should have only single copy in child context.

- If you are using plain-old XML configuration, the controller bean definition mu be placed in `*-servlet.xml` context, not in `applicationContext.xml` (if you stick to default naming).
- If you use component-scanning, make sure the main context does not scan controller packages or classes annotated with `@Controller`

If you are certain that only a single instance is created, it should work. Note that the controller can access `DataSource` (child context can access main context) but not the other way around.

#### Note 1

In similar cases it is enough to print:

```
System.out.println(this);
```

In the controller. Default `toString()` should give distinct results for different instances.

#### Note 2

Your error-handling should be improved. If this is not only for example purposes, always log full exception stack trace and avoid returning dummy results like empty string, which tend to hide errors.

Comment: I'll tell you, this is my first Java project, I created it with Roo, and I really don't understand much of what's happening in the XML configuration files. But I think it's clear that this object (and perhaps the whole application? Yikes.) is getting instantiated twice. I'll edit my question to include my config files, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Also, Roo didn't give me a *-servlet.xml file. It built a web.xml and an applicationContext.xml.

Comment: Ooh, I did just discover a `webmvc-config.xml` file.... And it does set up annotation scanning...